# Creating dynamic info for login tests using Python selenium in a pytest framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am trying to make 3 variables (user_name, user_password, user_email) that can be updated with a function that I call only once on the first test (for signing in) and then I need the data of the variables to be saved in them after that function was executed so I can use all them credentials for all of my test suits. so it goes something like this:

1. Run pytest
2. Pytest gets to test_suit_01 and runs the first test_01 in that class.
3. The test runs a function in another class called 'Helper' which updates the variables in that class
4. The test continues and the info that is stored in 'Helper' class variables is used to login to the user
5. The test finishes and the user is signed in with the credentials from the 'Helper' class
6. Pytest continues then to another test suit and uses the credentials that are saved to login and continue tests that INSIDE THE USER which call login function in conftest that uses the credentials created.

At this point when it gets to the credentials they are changed all the time or when I tried declaring them for user_name = None and then using that function the are always ' None'

I am accessing the credentials by Helper.user_name,Helper.user_password,Helper.user_email in conftest function for login before all the other test suits.

TO SUMMERIZE: I need 3 variables in class 'Helper' that I can update with a function inside that class and so they stay with the new info for all the test suits that use this 3 variables (different classes)

class Helper:

```
@classmethod
def create_user_info_file(cls):
    file_path = 'user_name_info.txt'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'{cls.user_name}\n{cls.user_email}\n{cls.user_password}')

@classmethod
def read_user_info_file(cls):
    file_path = 'user_name_info.txt'
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        cls.user_name = lines[0].strip()
        cls.user_email = lines[1].strip()
        cls.user_password = lines[2].strip()
@classmethod
def get_user_info(cls):
    return {
        'user_name': cls.user_name,
        'user_email': cls.user_email,
        'user_password': cls.user_password
    }

""" User info """
random_mail = 'tester' + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5]'
user_name = random_mail.split("@")[0]
user_email = random_mail
user_password = f'Pa#{str(uuid.uuid4())[:10]}'
```

After calling the 3 variables in a different class they were updated or None

Answer (score 0):

The best method for this would be a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html). This is a pytest feature that allows you to define automatic set up methods to your tests. It is bad practice to have program state that persists between tests so you should use this `setup_user` fixture in all your tests. I would do something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def setup_user():
    user = {
        "name": "test_username",
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "password": "password"
    }
    # Put more application setup here
    return user 

def test_print_user(setup_user):
    print(f"Hello {setup_user.name}!")
    # Other tests here
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply ! 
What if i need the name password and email to be updated and not static so lets say i called the setup_user.name ran 1,2,3... tests and then when i run the first test again i want it to change the name password and email ?

Comment: I think you will want parameterization (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html). This allows you to have multiple username/email/password combinations to test.